# Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server. in Recharts Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recharts

The following error occurs when I use the `Barchart` in `Recharts`.

> Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

But I don't know which code is causing it

**The following code gives an error**

```
import {NextPage} from "next";
import {Bar, BarChart, Brush, CartesianGrid, Legend, ReferenceLine, Tooltip, XAxis, YAxis} from "recharts";
import React from "react";
import {diffType} from "../@types";

type Props = {
    insName: string,
    data?: diffType[] | undefined,
}
const DiffBarChart: NextPage = ({insName, data}: Props) => {

    return (
        <>
            <BarChart
                width={900}
                height={300}
                data={data}
                margin={{
                    top: 5,
                    right: 30,
                    left: 20,
                    bottom: 5,
                }}
            >
                <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
                <XAxis dataKey="date_time"/>
                <YAxis/>
                <Tooltip/>
                <Legend verticalAlign="top" wrapperStyle={{lineHeight: "40px"}}/>
                <ReferenceLine y={0} stroke="#000"/>
                <Brush dataKey="date_time" height={30} stroke="#8884d8"/>
                <Bar dataKey="diff" fill="#8884d8"/>
            </BarChart>
        </>
    );
};
export default DiffBarChart;
```

---

**If I comment out some part of code below, the chart doesn't show up but the error doesn't occur**

```
import {NextPage} from "next";
import {Bar, BarChart, Brush, CartesianGrid, Legend, ReferenceLine, Tooltip, XAxis, YAxis} from "recharts";
import React from "react";
import {diffType} from "../@types";

type Props = {
    insName: string,
    data?: diffType[] | undefined,
}
const DiffBarChart: NextPage = ({insName, data}: Props) => {

    return (
        <>
            <BarChart
                width={900}
                height={300}
                data={data}
                margin={{
                    top: 5,
                    right: 30,
                    left: 20,
                    bottom: 5,
                }}
            >
                <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
                {/* <XAxis dataKey="date_time"/> */}
                {/* <YAxis/> */}
                {/* <Tooltip/> */}
                {/* <Legend verticalAlign="top" wrapperStyle={{lineHeight: "40px"}}/> */}
                {/* <ReferenceLine y={0} stroke="#000"/> */}
                {/* <Brush dataKey="date_time" height={30} stroke="#8884d8"/> */}
                {/* <Bar dataKey="diff" fill="#8884d8"/> */}
            </BarChart>
        </>
    );
};
export default DiffBarChart;
```

---

React : 18.2.0

Next : 13.4.4

Recharts : 2.6.2